# delete gitlab-runner-helper volume

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner, runner

when we use GitLab runner, the runner uses gitlab-runner-helper to create a volume to store data.

after a while when we try to get docker volumes we see many gitlab-runner-helper volumes with names like  "runner-wie4xt7--project-3-concurrent-0-cache-*"

To delete this volume I try to create a bash script file to remove volumes whose lifetime exceeds 24 hours

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Define the pattern for volume names to be removed
VOLUME_PATTERN="runner-wie4xt7--project-3-concurrent-0-cache-*"

# Define the maximum age of volumes in hours
MAX_AGE_HOURS=24

# Find and remove volumes matching the pattern and older than the specified age
docker volume ls -q -f name=$VOLUME_PATTERN | while read -r volume; do
  creation_time=$(docker volume inspect --format '{{.CreatedAt}}' "$volume")
  creation_timestamp=$(date -d "$creation_time" +%s)
  current_timestamp=$(date +%s)
  age_hours=$(( (current_timestamp - creation_timestamp) / 3600 ))

  if [ "$age_hours" -gt "$MAX_AGE_HOURS" ]; then
    echo "Removing volume: $volume (Age: $age_hours hours)"
    docker volume rm "$volume"
  fi
done
```

is there any way for docker or Gitlab runner to delete this volume automatically?